# What is a good strategy, other than NULLs, for dealing with unknown datetime values?

Tags: sql-server-2008, relational-database, database-normalization

My database has 3 tables: Organization, User & OrganizationUserJunction. The OrganizationUserJunction table tracks which organization a user belongs to, when they became a member of the organization, and when they left the organization. The MemberFrom field is populated with a known date but the MemberTo date is unknown at first. I do not like having NULL values in my tables.

When I am dealing with a string field I can populate them with 'UNKNOWN' rather than NULL. I would like to do something similar with datetime columns. What is a good strategy, other than nulls, for dealing with SQL Server datetime columns with an unknown value?

Comment: Related on DBA. [Why shouldn't we allow NULLs?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-shouldnt-we-allow-nulls)

Comment: Hopefully you've read the question that Mikael linked to, but if you have a real need for an alternative to `NULL` it would help to explain *why* you need it. What problem does `NULL` cause you? What do you want to achieve by not using it? So far you've just said that you don't like it, but that isn't very helpful in understanding the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Every nullable column in a design with nulls can be removed and a new table added with the old table's key plus the column not nullable. Keys of the original with a non-null value for the column go in the new table; those with a null don't. This is the straightforward relational design. (See sqlvogel's comment re "it's more a question of why you would choose to add nulls".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a legitimate question, and I am not sure why you were down-voted.

The correct answer, at least according to Joe Celko, is to use 9999-12-31 as your endDate. This is the official "end of time" according to ISO 8601.

You could also consider using 6th normal form (aka Anchor Modeling), which was designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

To take the example you've described. A current member does not have a MemberTo date therefore in the table for membership you don't need a MemberTo date. Put the MemberTo date in a table for ex-members (which would contain this and other attributes associated with ex-membership that do not apply to current members). No nulls are necessary to do this.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative nobody else has mentioned is to use separate tables for the two date columns. (On re-reading, I see the inimitable @sqlvogel did mention this. I'll leave the code as an example. If @sqlvogel wants to incorporate it into his answer, which I just upvoted, that's fine with me. I'll delete my answer afterwards.)

```
create table org_users (
  org_id integer not null references organizations (org_id),
  user_id integer not null references users (user_id), 
  member_from date not null default current_date,
  primary key (org_id, user_id, member_from)
);

create table org_users_member_to (
  org_id integer not null, 
  user_id integer not null,
  member_from date not null,
  member_to date not null default current_date
    check (member_to > member_from),
  primary key (org_id, user_id, member_from),
  foreign key (org_id, user_id, member_from) 
    references org_users (org_id, user_id, member_from)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with `NULL`? If the actual reason it's `NULL` is important (e.g. is the heart rate `NULL` because he's dead or because we didn't capture it yet), track that in a separate column (perhaps a `tinyint` FK'd to a lookup table called `dbo.DateIsNULLReasons` table).

All of the workarounds to this ("magic" date values, using INTs for all dates that lookup to a different table that has to have a `NULL`able column or store a magic date there instead) seem like hacks to me.

I think you should just get over your dislike of `NULL`s. They exist for a reason, such as specifying that the value is `unknown`, whether you like it or not, and regardless of the reason.

What do you gain by storing `UNKNOWN` instead of `NULL`? Do you know how much extra space that costs you in the table and any secondary indexes? Do you not find it annoying that you now have to filter that scenario out for certain queries?

Comment: There are many pros and cons on whether or not to use nulls. I have no desire to rehash the debate on this thread. This is a "how to" rather then a "why" question.

Comment: @Tarzan well, I addressed that too. IMHO the best practice is to allow `NULL`s, and track the reason separately if you need to. That doesn't preclude me from depositing the rest of my opinion, too. If you don't want opinions, you should hire a yes-sir consultant instead.

Comment: I think nulls are especially important for dates and numbers because there is no date/number equivalent of 'unknown'.  Putting an actual date in there will casue wierd results in any query using datemath (or you always have to exclude except when date = '01/01/1900'). Using 0 as a default for a number when you don't know it is disatrous as that is a real number and you can't tell which ones you know are 0 and which ones you do not know.

Comment: The question is pretty clear: what is a good strategy OTHER THAN NULLS for dealing with unknown date time values. Sorry if that was missed.

Comment: @Tarzan and as was already requested, if you can explain what you're trying to solve by avoiding `NULL`s, instead of just saying you don't like them, you might get more helpful responses. As it is, I don't see any practical value in avoiding `NULL`s, and I don't think any of the workarounds (again, as I described in my answer) justify satisfying an "I don't like it" request. If you ask the right question, you might get the right answer.

Comment: I asked the right question. If you have another topic, you can start another thread.

Comment: @Tarzan you're the one who is asking for help, why should I start a different question? I'm trying to help you but you don't seem to want help. You down-vote me because you don't like my answer, yet you haven't done anything that multiple people have asked you for (explain the **actual problem** you're trying to solve). If you act like this when you're trying to get help, don't be surprised when you don't get very useful help.

Comment: Nulls are always a compromise with reality because they don't accurately correspond to any information in the external Universe of Discourse (there are "no nulls in the real world"). Nulls are best understood as a technical feature inserted into a data model by database designers. From a modelling perspective therefore it's more a question of why you would choose to *add* nulls into a data model rather than why you would want to avoid them. I think Tarzan's problem statement is pretty clear really.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a default date for member review. Say 5 years after joining.

Or if we are dealing with a business organisation and you capture DOB and gender then you could calculate retirement age.

Personally I don't see an issue with NULL. In the context of MemberTo date, IS NULL = still a member. It serves exactly the same purpose as a default value and is far less complicated than a default date value being populated.

Comment: I am taking this approach with a slight modification. I set the default to January 1, 1900. I don't like having the default in the future. We will eventually reach the future date, unless the end of the world comes sooner. :)

Comment: All right, "magic" numbers FTW! Good thing you're avoiding big, bad, scary `NULL`s which are just as meaningless as January 1, 1900.

Comment: Another issue with this answer is that you can't just say "let's review membership after 5 years" because that creates a new business process. Someone now has to define what a review is, who does it etc. and that is obviously completely unrealistic. Similarly, retirement age changes as employment legislation changes, so now you have to add a business process to update your data when the law changes. I'm not sure how your users or customers would react to being asked to do more work so that IT can avoid using `NULL` values. Well, I am sure :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I stumbled upon it.

It's a good point that `null` should be avoided, especially for `DateTime`.

**Reason**: SQL server defaults `null` to something like `1/1/1900`. If you have use cases like `dateOfCasuality`, then you need to include special logic to handle DOB related rules.

**Possible solution**: Use a `ForeignKey` relation with another table containing dates. But that will increase schema complexity. However, I will never try to turn it into a string as that leads to a coding nightmare.